# How to perform subtraction based on '-' as string

Tags: python

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

I would like to get score of mathematical operation. How to solve that? The code is very easy and I think I don't have to explain it.

```
xlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8]
signxmin = '-'
parametrxmin = 1

for x in xlist:
    xmin = float(min(xlist)) + signxmin + parametrxmin
    print(xmin)
```

Comment: Hmm, why are you not doing `min(xlist) - parametrxmin`?

Comment: Since the code attempts to do something that frankly makes no sense - please do explain what it is supposed to do.

Comment: You define "signxmin", `signxmin` is a a variable with a type of "string", the string/contet is "-". A string is not a mathematical operator.

Comment: Why not just do `signxmin = -1` then do `xmin = float(min(xlist)) + signxmin * parametrxmin`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all variables in `xlist` are int, but `parametrxmin` is a string. Python cannot perform the 'add' operation between int and str objects.

Try these codes:

```py
xlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8]
signxmin = '-'
parametrxmin = 1

for x in xlist:
    xmin_str = str(x) + signxmin + str(parametrxmin)
    xmin = eval(xmin_str)
    print(xmin)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
xlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8]
parametrxmin = -1

for x in xlist:
    xmin = float(min(xlist)) +  parametrxmin
    print(xmin)
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).